# Android "Resources" Security

Tags: android, security, resources

I am building an Android app in which client is selling some mp3 files. Now my question is, when I copy these files in the resources folder, will they will be exposed when someone will explore the file system?

The reason why I am asking this question because I have seen application on Android market which can let you explore the android file system (you can also do this by attaching your device to your PC) and you can check what's in inside the application directory.

So if this is possible, how I can make sure my resources are secure?

Thanks.

Comment: devices can be rooted, my guess is no resources are secure

Comment: @binnyb - Is there any method to secure your resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Now my question is, when I copy these files in the resources folder, will they will be exposed when someone will explore the file system?*

#### Yes.

*So if this is possible, how I can make sure my resources are secure?*

#### You can't.

What you're asking for would only be possible on a [trusted computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Computing) (a.k.a. [treacherous computing](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/can-you-trust.html)) platform, which Android is not.

Comment: it means that android app sandbox is not as secure as iOS?

Comment: @itsaboutcode: It means that you are trying to make your application secure from the user who owns the very machine that this application runs on. This is fundamentally impossible unless you have a trusted system (ie. a system that is trusted not to obey its owner). See links above.