# How to secure raw folder in Android

Tags: android

I created a music app with my own music files. I placed all sound files in raw folder which is not secure. People just rename the `.apk` with `.zip` and started stealing my music file and they started coming with their own clones.

How can I secure raw folder?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like due to the nature of the Android `.apk`, resources are ultimately ex-tractable. Though you can prevent common methods like `.zip` using encryption, but the encryption key will need to be somewhere else in the application. Then you get to the secondary problem of attempting to hide that key. Alternatively you could use a web server to stream the music or send key for the encryption.

[Protecting code in android asset files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194322/protecting-code-in-android-asset-files)

[How to secure the android assets folder from hackers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683346/how-to-secure-the-android-assets-folder-from-hackers)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5275702/5686611

Comment: Any library to make it easy?

Comment: I found this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274768/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-audio-file-android

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I'd recommend is using a server to stream your music to the application. There are a lot of workarounds if you keep the data locally on android. Use a server, you'll be good to go.